# Python: skipping if the last sys.argv is empty

Tags: python

I run the script: python script.py arg1 arg2, but I want to do the trick, if the arg3 is provided then do something. Current code looking like this, but doesn't work.

```
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    pannot = open(sys.argv[3],"w")
    for v in anno2.values():
        pannot.write("\t".join(v))
        pannot.write("\n")
    pannot.close()
else: print("if you want to get an annotation, please, provide third argument")
```

The error is following: `IndexError: list index out of range`. Can you please suggest what is the problem? (script was tested under windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is because `script.py` is being passed as the first argument, so you should check :

```
if len(sys.argv) == 4:
```

Because the are four arguments :

```
['script.py', arg1, arg2, arg3]
```

Here is some working code :

```
emil ~/test > python script.py arg1 arg2 arg3
arg3
emil ~/test > cat script.py 
import sys
if len(sys.argv) == 4:
    print sys.argv[3] # do something
else:
    print("Please, provide third argument")
emil ~/test > python script.py arg1 arg2
Please, provide third argument
```

Comment: I need to check if arg3 is provided, if no - print message, yes - do smthing.

Comment: if len(sys.argv) > 3 work great, thank's, that was a stupid mistake

Answer (score 2):

To access the last element, use `sys.argv[-1]`. Or `sys.argv[2]` in your case. Lists have zero based indices. So, for a list of length 3, the last element would be at `testList[2]`.

If you want to check if the third argument was provided or not, you need to test for a length of 4.

```
C:\Python27>python scriptName.py 123 456 789
['scriptName.py', '123', '456', '789']
```

The first argument is the script name, so if you need to see how many additional arguments were passed, you need to check if `len(sys.argv) == 4` and then access the last element using `sys.argv[-1]`.

A test program to check that by testing the length of `sys.argv` would be.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 4:
    print "4 arguments were provided. The arguments were :", sys.argv[1:]
elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
    print "3 Arguments were provided. The arguments were :", sys.argv[1:]
```

Output :

```
C:\Python27>python scriptName.py 123 456 789
4 arguments were provided. The arguments were : ['123', '456', '789']

C:\Python27>python scriptName.py 123 456
3 Arguments were provided. The arguments were : ['123', '456']
```

Comment: the last argument doesn't exist, script should check if it's provided or not, if yes - do smthing, no - skip or print message.

Comment: So, you want to check whether a third argument was provided or not?

Comment: @JohnAmraph : I added a small snippet. See if this suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, `sys.argv` contains the name of the script and the arguments, so `len(sys.argv)` will be number of arguments + 1. So a simple script:

```
import sys
print len(argv)
```

gives:

```
$ python script.py
1
$ python script.py arg1 arg2 arg3
4
```